# can "could have" be either a past modal/auxiliary form as well as a stative form of have?

Tags: modal-verbs, stative-verbs

Consider the phrase, "is it possible, we could have rain (or rainy weather) on Saturday". This doesn't seem to be a past modal form as there is no verb it modifies, so seems more like a stative form of "have".

Comment: I don't understand the question.Why isn't _have_ considered to be a verb? It's an infinitive form and it follows a modal auxiliary verb; that's the description of a correct construction. There is an idiom involved -- _have rain,_ like _have a party_ or _have a fit,_ is an inchoative referring to change of state.

Comment: @JohnLawler  "have" is not an infinitive form.  "to have" is an infinitive form. OP was asking a kind of subtle question about a verbal color known as "stative".  'could' is modal; it cannot stand by itself.  The mode of 'could' modifies 'have', not the other way around!

Comment: @BadZen The 'infinitive form' of a verb is the verb form that goes after _to_ in most infinitives, and also goes after modal auxiliaries and _do_. It's used as the citation form for the verb, and in English is identical with the present tense form except for the verb _be_, which has a special infinitive form, alone of all English verbs. _To have_ is an infinitive phrase, not a verb form. The sense of _have_ in _have rain_ means 'experience rain' and it refers to weather, which is an event and has both active and stative verbs.